# Angular2 *ngIf Hiding the contents of a Div in the Template

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a form on my first Angular2 project, and I can't seem to get my `*ngIf` to hide a div in my template.

Here's my component file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Address } from './signup'

@Component({
  selector: 'address-area',
  styles: [],
  template: `
    <form name='addressForm' novalidate>

  <label> Get The Report via Standard Mail:</label>
  <input name='needAddress' class='checkbox' type='checkbox' [(ngModel)]='address.need' />
  <div *ngIf='isNeeded()'>
    <input name='add1' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Address Line 1' [(ngModel)]='address.add1' />
    <input name='add2' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Address Line 2' [(ngModel)]='address.add2' />
    <input name='city' class='text' type='text' placeholder='City' [(ngModel)]='address.city' />
    <input name='state' class='text' type='text' placeholder='State' [(ngModel)]='address.state' />
    <input name='zip' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Zip' [(ngModel)]='address.zip' />
    <input name='country' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Country' [(ngModel)]='address.country' />
  </div>
</form>
  `
})
export class AddressComponent {
  address: Address = new Address(false);
  isNeeded = function(){
    this.address.need == true;
  }
}
```

and just for reference, here is the class object.

```
export class Address{
  need: boolean;
  add1: string;
  add2: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  zip: string;
  country: string;
  constructor(public n: boolean){
    this.need = n;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to actually return something `return this.address.need;`.

Comment: Or just remove the method, and use `address.need` directly from the template. Renaming the field to `needed`, and moving it out of the Address class would also be clearer, IMHO. If it's needed, then you have an address, otherwise, you don't have one. Having an address that is not needed looks strange to me.

Comment: oh derp...... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isNeeded()` needs to return a value for `ngIf` to evaluate.

```
export class AddressComponent {
  address: Address = new Address(false);
  isNeeded = function(){
    return this.address.need == true; // returns the value
  }
}
```

Also, if you just want to show/hide elements, use style binding instead of `ngIf` because `ngIf` **removes** the elements from the DOM if the passed expression evaluates to `false` which is not efficient if it happens many times. You use style binding to show/hide elements like so

```
<div [style.display]='isNeeded() ? "block" : "none"'>
    <input name='add1' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Address Line 1' [(ngModel)]='address.add1' />
    <input name='add2' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Address Line 2' [(ngModel)]='address.add2' />
    <input name='city' class='text' type='text' placeholder='City' [(ngModel)]='address.city' />
    <input name='state' class='text' type='text' placeholder='State' [(ngModel)]='address.state' />
    <input name='zip' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Zip' [(ngModel)]='address.zip' />
    <input name='country' class='text' type='text' placeholder='Country' [(ngModel)]='address.country' />
  </div>
```

Now, your `div` will still be in the DOM, angular justs toggle its `style.display` property everytime the expression changes value